# Use Python to scrape images from xml tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a short python program to download of copy of the xml jail roster for the local county save that that file, scrape and save all the names and image links in a csv file, then download each of the photos with the file name being the name.

I've managed to get the XML file, save it locally, and create the csv file. I was briefly able to write the full xml tag (tag and attribute) to the csv file, but can't seem to get just the attribute, or the image links.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import requests
import csv
import bs4 as bs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get current date
today = date.today()

# convert date to date-sort format
d1 = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# create filename variable
roster = 'jailroster' + '-' + d1 + '-dev' + '.xml'

# grab xml file from server
url = "fakepath.xml"
print("ATTEMPTING TO GET XML FILE FROM SERVER")
req_xml = requests.get(url)
print("Response code:", req_xml.status_code)

if req_xml.status_code == 200:
        print("XML file downloaded at ", datetime.now())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req_xml.content, 'lxml')
        # save xml file from get locally
        with open(roster, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(req_xml.content)
            print('Saving local copy of XML as:', roster)

# read xml data from saved copy
infile = open(roster,'r')
contents = infile.read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(contents,'lxml')

# variables needed for image list
images = soup.findAll('image1')
fname = soup.findAll('nf')
mname = soup.findAll('nm')
lname = soup.findAll('nl')
baseurl = 'fakepath.com'

with open('image-list.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    imagelist = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    print('Image list being created')

    imagelist.writerows(images['src'])
```

I've gone through about a half dozen tutorials trying to figure all this out, but I think this is the edge of what I have been able to learn so far and I haven't even started to try and figure out how to save the list of images as files. Can anyone help out with a pointer or two or point me towards tutorials on this?

*Update: No this is not for a mugshot site or any unethical purposes. This data is for a private data project for a non-public public safety project.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the data you need:

```py
from datetime import date

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def extractor(tag: str) -> list:
    return [i.getText() for i in soup.find_all(tag)]


url = "https://legacyweb.randolphcountync.gov/sheriff/jailroster.xml"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, features="lxml")

images = [
    f"{'https://legacyweb.randolphcountync.gov'}{i['src'].lstrip('..')}"
    for i in soup.find_all('image1')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    zip(extractor("nf"), extractor("nm"), extractor("nl"), images),
    columns=['First Name', 'Middle Name', 'Last Name', 'Mugshot'],
)
df.to_csv(
    f"jailroster-{date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}-dev.csv",
    index=False,
)
```

Sample output (a `.csv` file):

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend a method for downloading all the images?

Comment: Load the file, choose the last column, and loop over the images, downloading them one by one.